# Scriptella: using collections and for each loop

Tags: java, collections, foreach, scriptella

How can I write the following code in scriptella?
It looks like it thinks that I'm trying to compare Set and String, and it does not like the last for loop.
And what is the way to write logical expressions like &&.
Thank you.

```
<connection id="java" driver="scriptella.driver.janino.Driver"/>

<script connection-id="java>

//some code

if(finalOrderCounter &lt; numberOfEntries){
    Set &lt;String> set = new HashSet &lt;String>();
    for(int i = 0; i &lt; fieldNames.length; i++){
        set.add(fieldNames[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i &lt; fieldNamesFromXML.length; i++){
        set.remove(fieldNamesFromXML[i]);
    }
    String exception = "";
    for(String element:set)
        exception += element +"\n";
    throw new IOException("Field(s)\n" + exception + "do(es) not exits in the source database");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the "classic" 'for' loop syntax?

```
StringBuffer exception = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i &lt; set.size(); ++i) {
    String element = (String) set.get(i);
    exception.append(element);
    exception.append("\n");
}
throw new IOException("Field(s)\n" + exception.toString() + "do(es) not exits in the source database");
```

BTW, what error are you getting?